# How to create white box scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to recreate [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3acQ5dDKEs), and oddly enough I do know how to create the water, glass, etc. However, I'm having trouble just creating the white walls around the scene in this video. Using the cycles render, what material do I set the walls to be? Also, how do i shade it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add in a cube and and delete three faces (top, one left and one right) this way you have enough light coming through and also have a light gray background and one sun lamp. This would be the way that I would recreate the scene.